# Task inputs vs task sources

Tags: gradle

Every Gradle task has property `inputs` of type `TaskInputs` that represents a collection of input files for a task. This is used mainly to recognize that task is up-to-date. However, some of the input files are also marked as *source* files - what does it mean? In other words, what is the difference between task input file and task source file?

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc for TaskInput.getSourceFiles()](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html):

> Returns the set of source files for this task. These are the subset of
>   input files which the task actually does work on. A task is skipped if
>   it has declared it accepts source files, and this collection is empty.

So it appears that source files are a subset of input files. Presumably, the task defines the "work" performed.